# Why is CROSS APPLY with Functions so slow compared to direct Function-Call?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a function that does return a table: `my_function(id integer)`

When I call this Function this way:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(123)
```

It takes about **1 seconds** to execute.

For some reasons I need to execute this function within a view, so I need to work around the parameters.

When I'm executing this, it takes about **20 seconds**:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM my_table AS m 
  CROSS APPLY my_function(m.id) AS p
WHERE m.id = 123
```

**Note:** `m.id` is unique, and the result is exactly the same.

Why is that?

Comment: you could post the execution plans for both

Comment: Perhaps 20 rows have the value 123 for `id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   m.id is unique

Comment: I just did `create fuNCTION my_function (@a int) RETURNS table AS  RETURN  select @a AS a` then your first select followed by `SELECT p.*
FROM sys.objects AS m 
  CROSS APPLY my_function(m.object_id) AS p`  Both nearly instant on a small db

Comment: @Lamak I cannot add the execution-planes, they are too big

Comment: @Cosinus, your comment *I cannot add the execution-planes, they are too big* points to the fact, that there must be more in the background. Try to isolate your issue. And you might want to read about [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)